# Is it possible to detect if user use our PWA from desktop or from mobile?

Tags: device, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on PWA, this is my first try with it. I have done the tutorial https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/ and few research but I didn't found anything about my problem : I would like to know if the user is using the app from his desktop or from a mobile, and then, if he uses the app from a desktop, change the start url (in order to go to a real website). Do someone have a clue ?

Comment: I think you can use [user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) but it's not reliable. Maybe you can check for screen size too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes user agent seems to be hazardous. I will try with screen sizes if I don't find something simpler

Comment: A PWA is a real website. If you are building something new, you may just want to figure out how to make your site responsive. So as the screen size changes, your website also changes to fit the screen. Then you only need to build one website. IMHO.

Comment: Yes I know that, but my goal is to make a lite version of an existing website (which is not adapted for mobile) only for mobile and redirect to the real website if user is on computer

Comment: found a solution?